# Using Param variable as @Table in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Dynamic SQL (passing table name as parameter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325044/dynamic-sql-passing-table-name-as-parameter)
> [Sql - tablename as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/sql-tablename-as-variable)

Is it possible to use a @param inside the stored procedure as a dynamic table name like this?

```
SELECT * FROM @tablename
```

Because i'm getting an error like this:

> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1,
>
> Must declare the table variable "@tablename".

`@tablename` is defined as a param, why am i seeing this?

Comment: I think this question has already been answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/sql-tablename-as-variable.