# use output of SQL statement as the table to run a query on

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I believe what I am attempting to achieve may only be done through the use of Dynamic SQL.  However, I have tried a couple of things without success.

I have a table in database DB1 (lets say DB1.dbo.table1, in a MS SQL server) that contains the names of other databases in the server (DB2,DB3, etc). Now, all the dbs listed in that table contain a particular table (lets call it desiredTable) which I want to query. So what I'm looking for is a way of creating a stored procedure/script/whatever that queries DB1.dbotable1 for the other DBs and then run a statement on each of the dbs retrieved, something like:

```
@DBNAME = select dbName from DB1.dbo.table1

select value1 from @DBNAME.dbo.desiredTable
```

Is that possible? I'm planning on running the sp/script in various systems  DB1.dbo.table1 being a constant.

Comment: You will almost certainly need to use Dynamic SQL to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic SQL (passing table name as parameter)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325044/dynamic-sql-passing-table-name-as-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a query dinamically and then execute it. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @MyDynamicQuery VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @MyDynamicDBName VARCHAR(20)

SELECT @MyDynamicDBName = dbName 
FROM DB1.dbo.table1

SET @MyDynamicQuery = 'SELECT value1 FROM ' + @MyDynamicDBName + '.dbo.desiredTable'

EXEC(@MyDynamicQuery)
```

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYYYYYYYYYYYYYY!! It works!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Awesome! Thanks soooooo much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the undocumented stored procedure, `sp_MSForEachDB`. The usual warnings about using an undocumented stored procedure apply though. Here's an example of how you might use it in your case:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'SELECT value1 FROM ?.dbo.desiredTable'
```

Notice the use of `?` in place of the DB name.

I'm not sure how you would limit it to only DBs in your own table. If I come up with something, then I'll post it here.