# Parametrized table name in SQL query

Tags: sql, vb.net, parameterized

I'm using Vb2005 to hit a SQL server. i have a pretty complicated query that hits identically structured databases on the server. I was looking into parameterizing the FROM clause but cant seem to do it. here is what i was trying

```
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * " & _
                        "FROM [@DB].[dbo].[Trips] AS T " & _
                        "WHERE T.DepartTime >= CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Sep 08, 2011', 120);"

    Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DB", SqlDbType.Char)
    cmd.Parameters("@DB").Value = "DriverDb"
```

Depending on the users needs I will hit the 'DriverDb' or the 'MaintDb' or 'DispDb' databases. the SQL string is actually much more complicated than that with references to the db in about 5 places so wanted to simplify it so that i could just replace with a parameter.

Comment: What about the connection string?

Comment: thats under control. i use a different connection string per user request.

Comment: I think the comment meant "What about setting the Initial Catalog in the connection string. ex. Initial Catalog = DriverDb

Comment: Yeah i guess i could do that. I hadn't thought of that approach. once i do that then i have to do get rid of the @Db in "FROM [dbo].[Trips] AS T" correct?

Answer (score 2):

I guess we can't do that for the DB name or table name which may not be considered as parameters. My suggestion would be to use a variable "db" and append that to the string "sql" something like below

```
Dim db As String = "DriverDb";
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * " & _  
                    "FROM ["& db &"].[dbo].[Trips] AS T " & _                         
                     "WHERE T.DepartTime >= CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Sep 08, 2011', 120);"
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: yeah that's what i have now, but I was just trying to make it cleaner by inserting the db name with a parameter. If you have a small query that's ok but with more complicated queries its a pain to not only code it but to change it later on.

Comment: In the end i just used a regex

Answer (score 1):

The following question's answer seems to sum it up pretty well.  [Dynamic SQL (passing table name as parameter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325044/dynamic-sql-passing-table-name-as-parameter)  You really should avoid dynamic SQL like this if at all possible.

Comment: The dynamic SQL could be avoided simply by a series of IFs.  (+1 for avoiding dynamic SQL.)

Comment: The databases that I'm hitting I have no control over. It just so happens that each database is identically structured and they hold data for different entities. Could it be revised to be one db with an id...yes but I cant control that part. but point taken, I just didn't want to write a complicated SQL where the only difference is the db name.