# Parameterized SQL in FROM clause

Tags: sql, parameterized-query

Using `OleDbCommand`. I can add SQL parameters and thus keep the query safe from SQL-injection, but is there a way to do this within the `FROM` cluase.See below

**THIS WORKS**

```
query = "Select * From Company Where @param = 1";
OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(query, sqlConnStr);

DataTable Table = new DataTable();
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
Table = null;

//Add Parameters
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param", "ID");
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
adapter.SelectCommand = Command;
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
Table = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

it returns a nice table with the wonderful row where id = 1

**BUT**

I am looking for something like this, note the FROM CLAUSE

```
query = "Select * From @tableName Where @param = 1";
OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(query, sqlConnStr);

DataTable Table = new DataTable();
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
Table = null;

//Add Parameters
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param", "ID");
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("tableName", "Company");
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
adapter.SelectCommand = Command;
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
Table = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

The DBMS keeps returning with `"Error in From clause"`

PS everything is spelled correctly - I triple checked

---

***To All - Thanks but Alas i shall stick to just Parameterized SQL. I don't like  `Dynamic SQL` One BIT***

Comment: According to Microsoft OleDbCommand does not even support named Paramters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx yet the top code excerpt works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to execute a dynamically concatenated SQL string, which unfortunately would compromise whatever benefits parametrized SQL had afforded you to begin with.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325044/dynamic-sql-passing-table-name-as-parameter).

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(250)
SELECT @SQL = 'Select * From ' + @TableName + ' Where ' + @param + ' = 1'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Not advisable, if you can predetermine the table name through some other means instead.

Comment: You should wrap @TableName and @param With [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx). i.e. `from ' + QUOUTENAME(@TableName) + ' where`. This not only reduces the chance of syntax errors due to table/column names being reserved words, or containing special characters.

Answer (score 1):

SQL doesn't support the FROM clause to be parameterized. You can't do it the way you are trying. Probably you can do like this:

```
query = "Select * From" + tableName + "Where @param = 1";
```

Comment: Yep correct, it is volunerable but that just's an example and show go for it at own risk.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use paramaterised object names. You would have to do somthing like

```
string.format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] WHERE [{1}] = 1", tableName, columnName);
```

**DO SO AT YOUR OWN PERIL**

It could be worth checking for square brackets in the input, this is the only way I can currently think off to "Inject" the above example. I am no hacker though and not versed in sql injection. Something like this **might** work:

```
        if (tableName.Contains("]"))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
```