# Query All Views In Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking to return a view name and all record ID's where billingAddress != shippingAddress to further review.  I need to query all views in one database.  This is my thought process and if their is a better way or faster way to write the query by all means help me out!

What I am stuck on is how to return the view name with the recordID?

```
Create Table #T (ID Int Identity Not Null, ViewNames VARCHAR(1000)
Create Table #2 (viewNames varchar(1000))
Insert Into #T (ViewNames)
Select '['+C.Table_Catalog+'].['+C.Table_Schema+'].['+C.Table_Name+']' TableName
FROM Information_Schema.Columns c
Join information_schema.Tables T on C.Table_Catalog = T.Table_Catalog 
AND C.Table_Schema = T.Table_Schema
AND C.Table_Name = T.Table_Name
Where T.Table_Type = 'View'
Group By '['+C.Table_Catalog+'].['+C.Table_Schema+'].['+C.Table_Name+']'
```

---Now this is the piece that I am stuck on as I do not know how to insert the view name into the table as well on each iteration

```
Declare @N int, @Str nvarchar(2000), @viewname nvarchar(2000), @MaxID int
Set @N = 1
Select @MaxID = Max(ID)
From #T
While (@N<@MaxID)
Begin
  Select @viewname= viewname
  From #T
  Set @Str = ' Insert Into #2(viewname)
  Select Top 1 '''+@viewname+'''
  From '+@viewname+'
  where exists(Select recordID from '+@viewname+' where [shipaddress] != [billaddress] ) '
  Exec sp_eecutesql @str
  Set @N = @N + 1
```

End
    Select * from #t

Comment: Lookup how to create dynamic SQL.  the problem is you can't select from a variable table name unless you use dynamic SQL.  Here's an example from a prior post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325044/dynamic-sql-passing-table-name-as-parameter

Comment: @xQbert - Syntactically my code above works for returning recordID's.  I just need a way of returning the viewname that recordID is associated with.

Comment: There are several errors in your code mate.

Comment: @king.code - let me restate.  The 1st statement executes error free.  The 2nd set that I am unsure of does not, was me attempting to show code of the output I was needing.  Still working on it tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your dynamic query like this.

You said you wanted the view name, and record id, so you need to add a column to #2

```
SET @Str = 'INSERT INTO #2(viewname, recordid)
SELECT ''' + quotename(@viewname) + ''', recordID 
FROM '+ quotename(@viewname) + '
WHERE [shipaddress] != [billaddress]'

EXEC sp_executesql @str
```

Unless you're sure of the object names, you should try and use quotename when building up dynamic SQL

You do have a problem in your logic though...

You are missing a where clause in the query that assigns the value to @viewname

Try this...

```
SELECT @viewname= viewname
FROM #T
WHERE ID = @N
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand sql returns set of rows so your variable @viewname can not be assigned value row by row. By default your @viewname will be assigned last row of table T.